# How to use super() to inherit a particular class from multiple father classes?

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, super

My code is like this, and I want to use super() to inherit the features of Papa, how to do that?

```
class Mama(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Mama'

    def feature(self):
        print "%s have big eyes" % self.name

class Papa(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Papa'

    def feature(self):
        print "%s have fierce beards" % self.name

class Offspring(Mama,Papa):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def feature(self):
        super(Offspring, self).feature()

offspring = Offspring('Tommy')

offspring.feature()

# This will result "Tommy have big eyes"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can alter the MRO (method resolution order) by inheriting from `Papa` *first*:

```
class Offspring(Papa, Mama):
```

The alternative is to skip the MRO and call the (unbound) method on `Papa` explicitly:

```
class Offspring(Mama, Papa):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def feature(self):
        Papa.feature(self)
```

Comment: It's you again being faster than me +1

Comment: I think the second way could be a decent solution for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

All the classes in your heirachy need to use `super` for it to go through *all* of the methods. Eventually, you will run into a problem whereby the next superclass is `object`, which doesn't have `feature`, so you also need to detect that case and ignore it - ie, you need to do this:

```
class Mama(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Mama'

    def feature(self):
        try:
            super(Mama, self).feature()
        except AttributeError:
            # only superclass is object
            pass
        print "%s have big eyes" % self.name

class Papa(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Papa'

    def feature(self):
        try:
            super(Papa, self).feature()
        except AttributeError:
            # only superclass is object
            pass
        print "%s have fierce beards" % self.name

class Offspring(Mama,Papa):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def feature(self):
        super(Offspring, self).feature()
```

Instead of catching the AttributeError, you could also make a further class that exists *only* to provide `feature` (without calling `super`) for other classes to inherit. Then both Mama and Papa inherit that class and override `feature`, like this:

```
 class Grandma(object):
     def feature(self):
         pass

 class Mama(Grandma):
     def feature(self):
        super(Mama, self).feature()
        print "%s have big eyes" % self.name
```

You *may* want to consider making `feature` an [abstractmethod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod), to emphasise that it exists only for inheritance.

In either case, what will happen is that you will *keep* calling the next method until you get to the end of the chain. If neither `Mama` nor `Papa` calls super, you will always stop after one call.

Comment: Thank you. I just want know here how to get the method of a desired father class. I've research a bit super this afternoon. If there are multi-level father classes have the same method. Just super(target_father_class, self).method() would call the father method of that father_class.